# VBA outlook change from of forwarded message

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to automatically forward a message but in the process, change the `From` field to another email address in our network which I have added to my Outlook (not as an account but as a mailbox under my own account and I can access it)

```
Dim recip As String

Dim allRecips As String
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.Folders("CSR GER").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Folders").Folders("#Confirmations")

i = 1

For Each olMail In Fldr.Items

    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "XXX BKG CONFIRMATION: " & BL) <> 0 Then

Set Recipients = olMail.Recipients
 For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
 recip$ = Recipients.Item(i).Address
 Debug.Print recip$
If VBA.Left(recip$, 10) = "/o=NOL-APL" Then
 GoTo Line2
End If

 If i = 1 Then
     strDomain = strDomain & recip
 Else
     strDomain = strDomain & recip & "; "
 End If
Line2:

 Next i
sentby = strDomain

    Set myItem = olMail.Forward

    myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "CSR_EST@xxx.com"

 myItem.Recipients.Add sentby

myItem.Display
```

Now the problem is with `SentBehalfOfName`. Once `myItem.Display` runs, the `From` field actually shows up correctly - `CSR_EST@xxx.com` but after sending the email you can see that it was sent by the mailbox that the email that is being forwarded is found - "CSR GER".

Can anybody help me understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own, here is what works for future reference:

For the .SentOnBehalfOfName to work, you need to first set it to null in the forwarded email, then create a copy and change it there.

```
Dim recip As String

Dim allRecips As String
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.Folders("CSR    GER").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Folders").Folders("#Confirmations")

i = 1

For Each olMail In Fldr.Items

      If InStr(olMail.Subject, "XXX BKG CONFIRMATION: " & BL) <> 0 Then

 Set Recipients = olMail.Recipients
For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
recip$ = Recipients.Item(i).Address

  If VBA.Left(recip$, 10) = "/o=NOL-APL" Then
       GoTo Line2
  End If

  If i = 1 Then
        strDomain = strDomain & recip
  Else
        strDomain = strDomain & recip & "; "
  End If

   Line2:

Next i
sentby = strDomain

Set myItem = olMail.Forward

 myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "" ' <- set value to null

myItem.Recipients.Add sentby

Set ittm = myItem.Copy ' <- copy the forwarded email  

 With ittm

 .SentOnBehalfOfName = "CSR_EST@xxx.com"

 .Display

 End With

 myItem.Delete '<- remove the forwarded email
```